# How to remove the hidden item space from Navigation Drawer when hiding a menu item?

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I have a SearchView to search on navigation drawer, it hides the elements that do not meet the search criteria, the problem is the hidden element spaces are still there.
How can i remove those spaces? Before search:

[image]

After search:
[image]

Code of SearchView onQueryTextListener

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        //Add Listener to SearchView when the Drawer is opened by first time
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
            if(searchView != null) return;

            searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.dw_searchv);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    //Access to menu items container
                    NavigationMenuView containerOfMenuItems = ((NavigationMenuView)((NavigationView)drawer.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0));
                    int options = containerOfMenuItems.getChildCount();

                    //Iterate the container of menu items
                    for(int i=0; i<options; i++){
                        Object menuItem = containerOfMenuItems.getChildAt(i);

                        //Verify that the Child of container, is an menu item
                        if(menuItem.getClass() == NavigationMenuItemView.class) {
                            String titleOfMenuItem = ((AppCompatCheckedTextView)((NavigationMenuItemView) menuItem).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
                            if(titleOfMenuItem.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
                                ((NavigationMenuItemView) menuItem).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            else {
                                ((NavigationMenuItemView) menuItem).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

PD: View.GONE doesn't works for me

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Try to use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: I added some code,

Comment: View.GONE doesn't works for me

Answer (score 0):

you have to add some code to show what do you use
anyway you can do the following for your case

1. you can create two lists one for searchResult and one for allData
2. if you want search results data put searchResult list in array of
   adapter and use notifyDataSetChanged method of adapter
3. if you want all views like of you cancel the search put allData list
   in array of adapter and use notifyDataSetChanged method of adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to modify the views composing the NavigationView, instead use the Menu that backs it:

```
// a field in your activity
private List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your onCreate() method keep a reference to the initial list of MenuItems:

```
//...
NavigationView nav = findViewById(R.id.yourNavViewId);
navMenu = nav.getMenu();
for (int i = 0; i < navMenu.size(); i++) {
    menuItems.add(navMenu.getItem(i));
}
```

Then in the onQuery method use that list:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
   NavigationView nav = findViewById(R.id.yourNavViewId); 
   nav.getMenu().clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.size(); i++) {
       MenuItem menuItem = menuItems.get(i);
       if (menuItem.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
          nav.getMenu().add(0, menuItem.getItemId(), 0, menuItem.getTitle());
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work, maybe i did not understand your code, can you be more especific?

Comment: But maybe it works, i need only to re-inflate or re-paint the navigation view, with the new menu, but i dont now how to do that

Comment: @LuisQuijada As I said, if you want to be able to revert back the search you need to keep a reference to the full list of menu items. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little late to answer. There is workaround/hack for this. No need to add list.
Just add this little line above your code. It surely works.

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
  
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.candidates -> {
                binding.navSideView.post {
                    navSideView.menu.findItem(R.id.candidateManagement).isVisible = !navSideView.menu.findItem(R.id.candidateManagement).isVisible
                }
            }
        
    }
    return true
}
```

You need to add navigationview.post Runnable before changing visibility. It will update the menu. It works with group too. :)